# Magento2 : How can override vendor/module-catalog to magento default theme?

Tags: php, magento-2.0

I am trying to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/*` ( `*` for whole module ).

I copied,

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/templates/*`

files under

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/Magento_Catalog/*
```

But I can't get any change of copied files. I don't have any custom theme.

How can I do this? I want to keep original files unchanged with my custom changes.

Comment: I edited your question because the formatting and punctuation signs were wrong

Answer (score 4):

You can override all files from vendor to our theme using below method.

Goto `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend`

Copy all folders and files to

`app\design\frontend\{Your_vendor}\{Theme_name}\Magento_Catalog`

Clear your cache using below command.

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Refresh your page you can see files from your theme.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as a theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/Magento_Catalog/
```

First, you have to create your own theme containing folder like:

```
app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Theme/Magento_Catalog
```

And select the theme from admin.

Then this folder will override core module_catalog

Comment: TS is asking for Vendor folder. Not App folder.